# Unknown exception in GeoServer WFS Insert request

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs-t

I am inserting polygon to my database using GeoServer Transaction Insert.
My code is:

```
'<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"\n' +
'xmlns:housenumber="http://www.openplans.org/housenumber"\n' +
'xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"\n' +
'xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"\n' +
'xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"\n' +
'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"\n' +
'xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd http://www.openplans.org/housenumber http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=housenumber:housetry">\n' +
'<wfs:Insert>\n' +
'<housenumber:housetry>\n' +
'<housenumber:geom>\n' +
gml3 + '\n' +
'</housenumber:geom>\n' +
'<housenumber:area>' + area + '</housenumber:area>\n' +
'<housenumber:name_house>' + name_house + '</housenumber:name_house>\n' +
'</housenumber:housetry>\n' +
'</wfs:Insert>\n' +
'</wfs:Transaction>\n'
```

I got this error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport  
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
    <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
        <ows:ExceptionText>
        Feature type 'housetry' is not available:  
        </ows:ExceptionText>
    </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Is `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=housenumber:housetry` really the schema location, I would expect a proper WFS DescribeFeatureType request like `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&typename=housenumber:housetry&`   (but possibly GeoServer does it differently)

Comment: @nmtoken I define schema location as per you mentioned and got different error.
`
<ows:Exception exceptionCode ="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen ...senumber http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/?service=WFS&request=... @7:199) 
entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen ...senumber http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/?service=WFS&request=... @7:199) </ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
`

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what schema you have, how you are invoking it, what you got, and what you expected to happen instead?

Comment: @nmtoken I followed your suggestion still the error is same.
I have my code like this in the GML part.
`                  var format = new ol.format.GML({
                    featureNS: 'housenumber',
                    featureType: 'housetry',
                    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
                  });
`
I think it has problem with the feature type part still couldn't figure it out.